# How to make a extension widget on the top right side of firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I port a Chrome extension to Firefox. Because the XUL-based API is quite different from Chrome API, so I use the [new add-on SDK](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.3/dev-guide/welcome.html) of firefox.

There is a interface called "widget" can be used to make a little icon button like "BrowserAction" of Chrome, but "widget" is on the bottom of window, "BrowserAction" is on the top right side of window.

Some firefox extensions, for example, [GreaseMonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/zh-cn/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) , have widgets on the top right, so I'm asking how to implement it using add-on SDK, not XUL based API?

Comment: Adding buttons to the main toolbar isn't recommended starting with Firefox 4 even though some add-ons still do that, the add-on bar is there for extension icons. The user can always customize the toolbar however and move your widget to the main toolbar.

Comment: Thank you, maybe I should follow the new style of Firefox.

Comment: It's worth noting that the Jetpack project's proposed roadmap for 2012 addresses this issue as a top priority: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Jetpack/Roadmap#Move_Add-ons_to_top_of_browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erik Vold has created a library that allows you to do this:

https://github.com/erikvold/toolbarbutton-jplib/blob/master/lib/toolbarbutton.js

While this code isn't included in the SDK libraries, it can be used to get the result you want with the current version of the SDK. You can see a quick example using Erik's library here:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/addon/1031142/latest/

Comment: The documentation on how to do it is here: https://github.com/erikvold/toolbarbutton-jplib/blob/master/docs/toolbarbutton.md