# how to add a  toolbar icon to firefox with firefox Add-on sdk

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

Just as the title says,the official course mentions  [WindowTracker](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.4/packages/api-utils/docs/window-utils.html),it may help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the [`widget` package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/packages/addon-kit/docs/widget.html). The very first example in the documentation already shows how you would use an icon as your widget.

Comment: I used the widget and the icon showed on the addon bar,not on the status bar which is just next to address bar.Thank you for help.

Comment: @lygu: There is no status bar starting with Firefox 4 - it was "merged" into the add-on bar and that's where extensions should be adding their icons. What you mean is a toolbar. See [Using JetPack to add toolbar buttons](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670282/using-jetpack-to-add-toolbar-buttons-integrating-xul-and-jetpack-for-firefox-ad) for an earlier question on this.

Comment: Thank you for help.It seems useful,but I don't know how to use it.I found  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633710/how-to-make-a-extension-widget-on-the-top-right-side-of-firefox">this question</a>,the answer gave a <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633710/how-to-make-a-extension-widget-on-the-top-right-side-of-firefox">example</a>,but it didn't work,the error information is "File "resource://jid1-izmxbb0vyfj9ma-at-jetpack-api-utils-lib/window-utils.js", line 76, in WindowTracker  this.delegate = delegate;TypeError: this.delegate is not extensible",how to solve it?Thanks