# Change position of firefox addon

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, xpi

Is there a way to change the position of the firefox addons from bottom to the top like chrome extensions. Anyway for example:

```
position:top,
```

Comment: Do you mean addons bar or addons icons?

Comment: the icon of the addon. I want to change it automatically when the addon is installed.

Comment: Does this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8633710/how-to-make-a-extension-widget-on-the-top-right-side-of-firefox) answer your question?